# Telegram bot using Telepot api and Webhook hosting on nginx

Tags: python, nginx, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to deploy a `Telegram Bot` using [Telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot) api and `Webhook` hosting on `Nginx`.
Here is my code (my_bot.py):

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, request
from telepot.delegate import per_chat_id, create_open, pave_event_space
import telepot
import requests
from settings import TOKEN, WAIT_TIME, PORT, URL

try:
    from Queue import Queue
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue

class MessageCounter(telepot.helper.ChatHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageCounter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def on_chat_message(self, msg):
        print(msg)
        # other stuff    

app = Flask(__name__)
update_queue = Queue()  # channel between `app` and `bot`

bot = telepot.DelegatorBot(TOKEN, [
    pave_event_space()(
        per_chat_id(), create_open, MessageCounter, timeout=10),
])
bot.message_loop(source=update_queue)  # take updates from queue


@app.route('/abc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pass_update():
    update_queue.put(request.data)  # pass update to bot
    return 'OK'

cf = open('cert', 'r')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.setWebhook(URL, cf)
    app.run(port=PORT, debug=True)
```

`URL` is the url of my server where `Nginx` is running.

beside this `my_bot.py` file i have a `settings.py` file which contains `TOKEN` and `URL` and `PORT` and a `cert` file which contains `ssl` certificate. I've also configured `Nginx` settings and i'm almost sure that the settings is correct.
Now when i try to run the code with `python my_bot.py` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: <html>  


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_bot.py", line 101, in <module>
    bot.setWebhook(URL, cf)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 638, in setWebhook
    return self._api_request('setWebhook', _rectify(p), files)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\telepot\__init__.py", line 398, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\telepot\api.py", line 130, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 148, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 244, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 671, in urlopen
    release_conn=release_conn, **response_kw)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 303, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot343287574:AAGJPgohCCviXA2RawmMqgucUKRJDZK3Z7o
/setWebhook (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('<html>\r\n',)))
```

Sorry for the bad format of the error message, what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Set the webhook once with just a GET request in your browser. Then proxy pass the incoming POST requests to the spawned telepot server.

Comment: @MohammedSohail Thanks, that fixes the problem.